# fminsearch-likelihood estimation for grid valued function

Tags: matlab, parameters, estimation

I want to create a multivariable(here four) function with a grid and than interpolate it for any X,Y. Assuming that is my probablity density function I calculate their marginal on X. I use this function to built a dataset. Each of my M-Files runs well,at least I think so. But I recieve an error, when I let run the estimation part. Could you please help me, if my mistake is mendable.

```
    clear all;
    %%%Some parameters
    m1=0.01;
    m2=0.02;
    m3=0.001;
    Z=zeros(10,20,10,5);
    % MFILE1
    %Create a four variable function 
    % function w=anemon(m1,m2,m3,X,Y,k,l)
    % w=(m1*k+(m1+m2).*l)+X.*exp(-m3.*Y);
    % end

    % MFILE2
    %Interpolate any (Xstar,Ystar) with a nonsence interpolation code
    %I wrote it only for giving an example
    % function p=interpanemon(Xstar,Ystar,m1,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,kk,ll)
    % p=0;
    % for i=1:length(X)-1
    %     for j=1:length(Y)-1
    %           if ((Y(j)<=Ystar)&&(Ystar<=Y(j+1)))&&((X(i)<=Xstar)&&(Xstar<=X(i+1)))
    %           p=(Z(i,j,kk,ll)+Z(i+1,j,kk,ll)+Z(i,j+1,kk,ll)+Z(i+1,j+1,kk,ll))/4;
    %          end
    %     end
    % end
    %     return
    %  end

    % MFILE3
    %Create a model which I'm going to use for parameter estimation
    % function loglik= modelanemon(p)
    % global n x m2 m3 kk ll ;
    % f =marjinteranemon(Ystar,p,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,kk,ll); 
    % loglik0=(-1)*(x.*log(f)+(n-x).*log(1-f));%minus likelihood
    % loglik=sum(loglik0);
    % end

%%
    X=linspace(0,10,6);
    Y=linspace(0,20,6);
    for k=1:10
        kk=k-1;
        for l=1:5
            ll=l-1;
    for i=1:length(X)
        for j=1:length(Y)
            Z(i,j,k,l)=anemon(m1,m2,m3,X(i),Y(j),kk,ll);
        end
    end
        end
    end
    %%%Now run all M-Files for self control
    anemon(m1,m2,m3,X,Y,4,5)
    interpanemon(3,4,m1,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,4,5)
    marjinteranemon(3,Z,X,Y,m1,m2,m3,4,5)

%STARTING PROBLEM PART


%SCRIPT fminsearch, I will be greatful if you have any advise. This part of        %       code  doesn't work
    % global n Ystar x kk ll m1 m2 m3;
    % m1=0.1;
    % m2=0.2;
    % m3=0.3;
    % Ystar=[1 3 6 9 12 18]';
    % kk=[1 1 2 3 3 4]';
    % ll=[0 0 1 3 4 5]';
    % y=marjinteranemon(Ystar,Z,X,Y,m1,m2,m3,kk,ll);
    % n=100;
    % x=y.*n;
    % pstart=5;
    % [p1,modelvalue]=fminsearch(@modelanemon,pstart);
```

Comment: Can you post the error that you are seeing?  I get: `??? Undefined function or variable 'mu'.` from the `anemon` function, should that be `m3`?

Comment: @macduff Thank you for your quick answer! Errors fallow:            'Error in ==> modelanemon at 3
f =marjinteranemon(Ystar,p,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,kk,ll);

Error in ==> fminsearch at 205
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});'

Comment: what should the value of mu be?  Forgive me if this is obvious.  I am also missing the function `marjinteranemon()`

Comment: I fixed it after your @macduff notice and replaced with m3:)

Comment: did that solve your problem?  Also, as a personal favor could I see the `marjinteranemon()` function?

Comment: unfortunataly not:( thank you again for your interest! Here is the M-File for marjinteranemon():'function f = marjinteranemon(Ystar,m1,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,kk,ll)
sum=0;
 XX=linspace(0,10,12);
  for i=1:(length(X)-1);
     sum=sum+interpanemon(XX(i),Ystar,m1,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,kk,ll).*(XX(i+1)-XX(i));
  end
  f=sum;
end'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7983/discussion-between-macduff-and-user1018331)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the `anemon` function, mu should be m3.
2. Since you're trying to estimate the parameter m1, you'll need to pass all other data to the `modelanemon` function as parameters or globals.

I usually wouldn't recommend globals, but I think it may be a little too advanced to try passing parameters to local function handles.  :-)  You're code will be something like this:

```
    % MFILE3
    %Create a model which I'm going to use for parameter estimation
    function loglik= modelanemon(p)
      global Ystar m2 m3 Z X Y kk ll n x;
      f =marjinteranemon(Ystar,p,m2,m3,Z,X,Y,kk,ll); 
      loglik0=(-1)*(x.*log(f)+(n-x).*log(1-f));%minus likelihood
      loglik=sum(loglik0);
    end
```